# How do I determine switching textarea focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textarea:

```
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

Now I want to show this message `text area was focused` **once until focus on the another textarea**.

Something like this:

```js
var el;
$("body").on('focus', 'textarea', function(e) {

  if (el != $(this)) {
    alert('new textarea is focused now');
  }
  
  el = $(this);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

This ^ code works if I never blur any of those text area(s) after first focused. But if I blur one of them, then this variable `el` will be empty .. How can I keep `$(this)` into `el` forever?

Comment: What is your actual goal? `this` will always refer to the event target in a jquery event handler so `$(this)` can not really be manually set

Comment: `$(this)` always creates a new object. Instead, do `el != this` and `el = this`.

Comment: @MikeC The problem is still there https://jsfiddle.net/and22ogu/

Comment: @stack You didn't fix your assignment. `el = $(this)` should be `el = this`.

Comment: @RobM. My goal is which textarea has been focused in the last time ...

Comment: @stack sorry for asking but it got me really curious... Why did you open bounty of 500 points for this? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is using `this` instead of `$(this)`, like this:

```js
var el;
$("body").on('focus', 'textarea', function(e) {

  if (el != this) {
    alert('new textarea is focused now');
  }
  
  el = this;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an alert which will blur the rest of the page. Once you dismiss the alert dialog the text area wil be back into focus. This creates a crazy and never ending cycle of (event - alert - event). use `return` to exit once it fires.